# Как заменить точку на запятую в типе Double?

Tags: swift, клавиатура, типы-данных, double, ввод

Есть такой код:

```
import UIKit

class YearsViewController: UIViewController {

var a: Double = 0
var b: Double = 0

@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var cLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
}

 @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {

a = Double(textField.text!)! 

b = Double(a * 52.1429)

cLabel.text = "\(b)"
    }

}
```

Проблема в том, что для textField я настроил клавиатуру "Decimal pad" и при попытке ввода числа с запятой (3,43255 или 765,001234) стопорится приложение. 
Есть ли возможность заменить точку в Double на запятую или настроить точку вместо запятой на клавиатуре?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что инициализация значения типа Double строкой типа "3,43255" дает nil. А затем вы делаете forced unwrapping для nil: (nil)!, и естественно приложение крешится. В вашем коде

```
a = Double(textField.text!)!
```

это второй восклицательный знак.
Чтобы преобразовать введенную строку в системный тип Double нужно использовать NumberFormatter, который учитывает локализацию приложения (в большинстве стран десятичный разделитель это запятая, но во многих странах это точка, и тогда Decimal Pad будет показыать точку в качестве разделителя, а не запятую). Вот пример кода:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale.current
if let number = formatter.number(from: "3,43255") {
    a = number.doubleValue // - > a = 3.43255
}
```

Comment: а если мне NumberFormatter встраивать к текстовому полю? В "if let number = formatter.number(from: "3,43255")" мне же надо будет указать на переменную, которую ввожу в текстовое поле (а это а)? В таком случае компилятор ругается, что мое значение в Double, а не в стринг

Comment: А кстати без второго воскл. знака он вообще не хочет воспринимать введенные мной данные

Comment: if let text = textField.text, let number = formatter.number(from: text) {
 a = number.doubleValue
}

Comment: Вы не можете просто так убрать восклицательный знак, потому что у вас переменная а типа Double, a то, что вы пытаетесь ей присвоить, типа Double?. Поэтому вы вынуждены делать forced unwrapping (ставить восклицательный знак). Вообще перед использованием переменных типа Optional нужно либо проверять, что в этой переменной содержится значение не nil, либо использовать конструкцию if let, как в моем предыдущем комментарии. Использование forced unwrapping чревато крешами, что и произошло в вашем примере.

Comment: Подробное описание концепции Optionals и Forced unwrapping в документации: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Comment: Спасибо большое!